# How to crop keras image tensor dependent on model input?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, slice, tensor

I want to create a keras network that gets a masked image (image with a rectangular region filled by zeros) as one input and information about the position of this region as a second input:

- Input 1: masked_image, shape=(128, 128, 3)
- Input 2: mask_pos, shape=(2,) or (4,), depends on whether or not the region size is fix or also variable.

I want to let my network fill in the "zeroed" region and extract this reconstructed region of the model output afterwards.

The main problems I encountered today are:

1. slicing a tensor in general
2. confusion about if I need to think in terms of batches, or if keras handles that for me
3. how to use values from the second input in the slicing/cropping procedure

Here is the code snippet of my current attempt. The last line basically presents where I am stuck now: I need to fill in the values **BOX_X**, **BOX_Y** and **BATCH_SIZE** in a way that they dynamically adapt to the inputs while the network is training.
*I would reaaally appreciate any help, I'm trying to figure that out for very long now*:

```
# get masked image and bounding box information as inputs
masked_img = Input(shape=self.input_shape)
mask_pos = Input(shape=(2,), dtype="int32", name="input-mask-position")

# fill in the masked region and extract the fill-in region
filled_img = self.generator(masked_img)
fill_in = Lambda(lambda img: K.slice(img, (0, BOX_X, BOX_Y, 0), (BATCH_SIZE, 32, 32, 3)))(filled_img)
```

I tried a little bit further, but get an annoying error message :/

```
 def extract_mask_region(img, box_x, box_y):
        return K.slice(img, (0, box_x, box_y, 0), (32, 32, 32, 3))

 fill_in = Lambda(lambda args: extract_mask_region(args[0], args[1], args[2]))([filled_img, mask_pos[1], mask_pos[0]])
```

Error Message:
    _ValueError: Tried to convert 'begin' to a tensor and failed. Error: Shapes 
    must be equal rank, but are 1 and 0
    From merging shape 2 with other shapes. for 'lambda_28/Slice/packed' (op: 'Pack') with input shapes: [], [2], [2], []._

Comment: Honestly I am kind of disappointed in tensorflow that we still can't do this.  I've been looking through thread after thread and I am not finding a way to do this that can use vectorized operations.  I can't even convert the tensor back into a numpy array because tensorflow says that it's purely symbolic.